# Can't add new project to collection in TFS2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am learning how to set up TFS2015 on a private server, and am following [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project) guide. Step 4 on that guide clearly shows a button for creating a project. This is how it looks like on my TFS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tIGi.jpg

As you can see, there's no "New Team Project" button. So far, I've tried going to the security tab, and adding "Create New Project" permissions to every group I see. I am logged in as the Windows Server admin (it's a virtual machine for private use, so no worries about messing up security). I added permissions for creating a new project to the admin account, who I am also logged in as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH3JV.jpg

But still no option to create a new project. What is going wrong?

Comment: There's something odd though... I would've expected to see all of the Project Collection groups properly configured under the Security tab of your collection. Did you removed them?

Comment: @DanielLessard Sorry for the late reply: nope, I did not remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the account you're using for opening a session on the TFS web site is member of one of the following groups: **Team Foundation Administrators** or **Project Collection Administrators**.

To add this account to one of these groups, you must open the TFS Admin Console on the server and configure it from there.

For details, please refer to the following article:
[Add administrators to Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/add-administrator-tfs)

Answer (score 0):

Only when you're using TFS 2015 Update 2 or later then you can create a team project from the web. Check your TFS edition and it's recommended to upgrade your TFS 2015 to the latest edition TFS 2015 Update 3.